# Bootstrap-datepicker date with or without day

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Is it possible to have multiple date formats? For example I have currently dd/mm/yyyy, but now theres need for mm/yyyy if no day specified.

I have found theres extraFormats option but it's just how it formats the date? Picker must allow to set date with or without day.

Code:

```
autoclose: true,
format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
extraFormats: ['mm/yyyy'],
minViewMode: 'days',
startView: 'decade'
```

Comment: I have now done a workaround, for now: year, month and day have each separate input, own min/maxview (decade, year, month), and when you press the button it combines this to mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format for posted, depending if the day was given or not. However, this is not longterm solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**check this code**

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
```

**refer this** http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
The example (5th) where it limits to months.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dpMonths" data-date="102/2012" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-minviewmode="months">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="02/2012" readonly="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#dpMonths').datepicker();
```

Comment: Read the question, "IF no day specified", so it should allow both formats with day dd/mm/yyyy AND without day mm/yyyy